# Design Pattern to wrap a series of step

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm having a financial related service that enable our users to topup their balance in our system, and then disburse the money. They'll be charged for each disbursement.
The problem is, I'm having a need to do a series of step that need to be done in several places.

Related component:

- Transaction : record of the transaction info (amount, beneficiary account, etc)
- Payment : record of the payment info (amount, payment status)
- Journal Entries : record the flow of money for every transaction and payment (for every movement of money in our system, we track which account act as the debit account and which as the credit account, like in accounting)

Flow of the business process:

- Suppose there's a transaction and payment already created, next step is to confirm the transaction
- Change transaction status to confirmed
- Change payment status to confirmed
- Insert new record to journal entries, with debit and credit account specified specifically for this process
- Increment or decrement the balance of the credit and debit account

Those series of step might be done in several places, so I try to find a way to prevent other programmer that try to implement this flow forgetting a step or doing it wrong.

What I do now:

- **Create a journal entry helper**. Consist of a lot of static function for each of possible business process that involve moving money between accounts. For example in this question, when confirming a payment, it moved money from `user_deposit` to `unearned_revenue` account, so `user_deposit` will be the debit account, and `unearned_revenue` will be the credit account in the newly inserted journal entry. Each of this static function only differ in telling which account will be the credit account and which will be the debit account. Beside that, this helper will also decrement or increment the balance of the credit and debit account. So in this example, it will decrement `user_deposit` balance and increment `unearned_revenue` balance. Example function name related to this example: `withdrawPayment` and `withdrawTransaction`
- **Create a payment helper**. Different payment type, in different state, will need different journal entry helper. So there are a lot of static function in this helper that change the payment status, and then call the related journal entry helper. Example function name related to this example: `confirmAndWithdrawCashPayment`
- **Create an instance method on the transaction** named like `confirmAndwithdraw`, which will call `confirmAndWithdrawCashPayment` on payment helper and `withdrawTransaction` on journal entry helper, which will call `withdrawPayment` on journal entry helper.
- Whenever a programmer need to do this step, they just call the `confirmAndwithdraw` function from the transaction object

This'll work of course, but I also know that this is a very bad design. Any suggestion of a design pattern or any solution suitable for this case?

Mainly, I'm looking for a way to wrap a series of steps so that I can remove those helper class while also providing a convenient way for other programmers to implement this business process.

Sorry for the long question. If the question is not clear, please do tell me so I can provide more information.

Comment: This question isn't just too broad, it will also mainly attract opinion-based answers (which are off-topic here).

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson, thank you for commenting. Any suggestion to improve this question? At least to make it not too broad.

Comment: You should do a lot of research, write some code and come back if you run into some specific issue with your existing code. Currently, the question is more suited at some discussion forum than here in SO (which is for concrete questions that has concrete answers).

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios like this where instantiating a type requires a certain order of steps I recommend taking a look at the Builder Pattern. This way you can chain the required steps and execute them at any time (deferred) by storing an intermediate state of the object. When done you would call build() an receive the initialized instance. Each method of the builder can return a different object so that you can force the client to use only a selection of methods depended on the prior invoked operation.

Could look like this:

```
PaymentBuilder paymentBuilder = new PaymentBuilder();
paymentBuilder.OpenTransaction(); 
// PaymentBuilder e.g. has only the OpenTransaction() method which returns a 
// PaymentTransactionOptions instance. This instance contains the 
// state of OpenTransaction() and adds further information by 
// invoking its SetPayment() method. 
paymentBuilder.OpenTransaction(args).SetPaymentMethod(moreArgs); 
// SetPaymentMethod(moreArgs) returns a PaymentJournalOptions instance 
// that contains the prior collected information and a method SetJournalData(). 
paymentBuilder.OpenTransaction(args).SetPaymentMethod(moreArgs).SetJournalData(journalArgs);
```

You continue like this until your transaction data is complete for execution. Then you invoke (on the last result object) build() to retrieve the build instance which may exposes a method 'commit()'.
Instead of chaining the method calls you could store the intermediate result and pass it around and complete it at any point in code you like.